# glmulti - multicore options?

Tags: r, glm, rjava

I am using the 'R' library "glmulti" and performing an exhaustive search.

relevant code:

```
local1.model <- glmulti(est, # use the model with built as a starting point
                        level = 1,  #  just look at main effects
                        method = "h",
                        crit="aicc") # use AICc because it works better than AIC for small sample sizes
```

The variable "est" is a fitted GLM that informs glmulti.

If I were a Java-based program that had to do the same thing several hundred thousand times, then I would use more than one core.

My glmulti is not using my cores efficiently.

[image]

Is there a way to switch it to make use of more of my system?

Note: when I use 'h2o' it can max out the CPU and make a strong hit on the memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R is single-threaded (unless the function is built on a library with its own threading). You can manually add parallelization to your code, using the rparallel library (which is part of core R): http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf

I would class it as non-trivial to use. It is a bit of a hack on top of R, so it does lots of memory copying, and you need to think about what is going on if you care about efficiency.

[glmulti](https://cran.r-project.org/package=glmulti) looks like it ought to be parallel (i.e. each combination of parameters could be done in parallel, even if using a genetic algorithm). My guess is they intended to add it, but development stopped (no updates since Sep 2009).